# Target KeyboardInterrupt to subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I wish to launch a rather long-running subprocess in Python, and would like to be able to terminate it with `^C`. However, pressing `^C` leads to the parent receiving `KeyboardInterrupt` and terminating (and sometimes leaves `sleep` as a defunct process).

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("sleep 100".split())
```

How do I have it such that pressing `^C` only terminates the `sleep` process  (as we'd have on a shell command line), and allow the parent to continue? I believe I tried some combinations of using `preexec_fn`, `start_new_session`  and `shell` flags to `call`, but with no success.

**Edit**: I know I can wrap the `subprocess` invocation in a `try-catch` block, and ignore the keyboard interrupt; but I don't want to do that. My question is this: the keyboard interrupt should have killed the `sleep`, and should have been the end of it. Why is then propagated, as it were, to the parent. Or is it like the `sleep` process was never the one to receive the interrupt? If not, how would I make it the foreground process?

Again, I'm trying to emulate the parent-child relationship of a command line. If I were to do the equivalent on a command line, I can get away without needing extra handling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Jacob, one way (thanks to a colleague) to do is to handle SIGNAL and pass it on to the child. So a wrapper like this would be:

```
import signal
import subprocess

def run_cmd(cmd, **kwargs):
    try:
        p = None

        # Register handler to pass keyboard interrupt to the subprocess
        def handler(sig, frame):
            if p:
                p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
            else:
                raise KeyboardInterrupt
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
        if p.wait():
            raise Exception(cmd[0] + " failed")
    finally:
        # Reset handler
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `signal` to catch SIGINT, and make the signal handler terminate the subprocess.

Look at this for more information (if it's for Python 2.x):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a workaround but it works fine (at least on Windows which handles CTRL+C differently)

```
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.call(r"C:\msys64\usr\bin\sleep 100".split())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("** BREAK **")
print("continuing the python program")
```

execution:

```
K:\jff\data\python>dummy_wait.py
** BREAK **
continuing the python program
```